# matrix logarithm, determination and trace maxmimzation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = A^\ast \in M_n$ be a positive definite matrix ($\lambda_i(A) > 0$). Show that

$\log\det(A)-Tr(A)$

is maximized by $A = I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $\lambda_i>0$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, are the eigenvalues of $A$, then
$$\tag{$*$}
\log\det(A)-\mathrm{tr}(A)=\log\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i-\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i=\sum_{i=1}^n f(\lambda_i), \quad f(\lambda)=\log\lambda-\lambda.
$$
The function $f$ has on $(0,\infty)$ the global maximum at $\lambda=1$ and hence ($*$) has the global maximum at $\lambda_1=\cdots=\lambda_n=1$. Hence $A=I$ maximises ($*$).